# How can I filter on the number of rows in the value column of a group-by in Nushell?

Tags: elasticsearch, nushell

I want to do the equivalent of a HAVING clause in SQL. The real life description is I'm trying to find Elasticsearch aliases that point to two (or more) indexes and their index names. The data looks like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-alias.html#cat-alias-api-example).

I first do a *group by*, then I pivot them to get rows, where the first column is the group key and the second column is a table with n rows. The command to get this table is `open file.txt | lines | split-column " " --collapse-empty Alias Index | group by Alias | pivot`

```
 ──┬───────────────┬────────────────
 # │ Column0       │ Column1
───┼───────────────┼────────────────
 0 │ abcd_20200430 │ [table 1 rows]
 1 │ abcd_20200501 │ [table 3 rows]
 2 │ abcd_20200502 │ [table 2 rows]
 3 │ abcd_20200503 │ [table 1 rows]
 4 │ abcd_20200504 │ [table 1 rows]
```

I want to filter this table by the rows where Column1 has more than 1 row. How would I do that?

`| where Column1.count > 1` doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding another column with their sizes as a workaround. Something like this:

```
open file.txt | lines | split-column " " --collapse-empty Alias Index | group by Alias | pivot | default size 0 | update size { get Column1 | count }
```

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Nushell you should be able to use `where` and `length` like so:

`where ($it.Column1 | length) > 1`